# Dell laptop display grainy on darker colors

Tags: graphics-card, hardware-failure, colors

I've recently been provided a new Dell Precision "laptop" with shipped-in ATI FirePro M7820 card. And for some reasons I'm experiencing "grain" flickering on dark colours (mostly grey) but not on all black.

The problem does not raise on a TV-screen or other external screen, so I guess I may have to tune up my screen and/or graphic card settings to make it disappear.

Does someone know about what tuning I can do to avoid this annoyance?

#### Edit:

Graphic card driver reinstalled but still the same.

Comment: Is there anyone else that's "been provided" this same model laptop that you could compare screens with?  The way you phrased it makes it sound like it was given to you through your job, for example.

Comment: Yep, university gave me this laptop for my research work. And it's brand new :P. They got it through professional Dell center I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would bet it's a faulty LCD screen.  I had a Dell Latitude D630 a couple years ago with a similar problem.  Sometimes things fall through the cracks in QC.  Especially since it's new and sounds like a workmanship or hardware defect, there shouldn't be much problem getting the screen replaced under warranty.  Might want to let IT support for whoever gave it to you handle that though.